# Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I followed this code here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver

I am trying to get access token back.

I have a problem, I am running SpringBoot 3.0.4 but also tried all of the following **3.0.0** to **3.0.3** as well.

I get an error **"error": "invalid_client"** when the authentication method is set to **ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC**
but when I change the method to **ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE**, I get the token back. What causes this issue?.

The full error trace below.

```
    org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: authentication_method
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.PublicClientAuthenticationProvider.throwInvalidClient(PublicClientAuthenticationProvider.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.PublicClientAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PublicClientAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java:86) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:84) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationServerContextFilter.java:61) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrong authentication method is being used for requests that have the resource owner password credentials grant type and the openid scope or a grant type of client_credentials.

This issue is only seen when using the openid scope, as this is an `OIDC` concept. According to the OpenID standard, the client authentication method can be defined in the configuration of the `OAuth2` provider (in this case AM). If no method is selected, the `client_secret_basic` method is used by default.

This issue can be resolved by setting the Token Endpoint Authentication Method to `client_secret_post`.

You can check more information here:

[invalid_client error when requesting an OAuth 2.0](https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a27814899)

**Edit:**

Check this point at `AuthorizationServerConfig` class, that seems to be what gives you problems:

```
http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                    .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
```

**It seems your problem is more related to `OIDC` than `Spring`.**

You can also expand this information [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication):

`client_secret_basic` Clients that have received a client_secret value from the Authorization Server authenticate with the Authorization Server in accordance with Section 2.3.1 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] using the HTTP Basic authentication scheme.

`client_secret_post` Clients that have received a client_secret value from the Authorization Server, authenticate with the Authorization Server in accordance with Section 2.3.1 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] by including the Client Credentials in the request body.

Comment: I tried to change to client_secret_post but I got the same error. I tried other methods. I beginning to think it's the issue with Spring

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that this didn't help you, I have edited my answer to expand information.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this problem for a few days while working on my personal project. After thoroughly reading documentation and searching for solutions on GitHub and StackOverflow, I am able to solve the issue.

**Problem:**

While creating RegisteredClientRepository @Bean, the client's secret password is String. While requesting access tokens through the POST method using Postman. Debugging the request in IntelliJ I get, *Password does not look like BCrypt*; in my case, I have implemented Bcrypt Password Encoder. So it's unable to authenticate the client and Authorized filter invocation is not executed successfully. This is what I have understood. Please correct me if I am not on the correct track and help me to understand more about the topic.

```
var registerClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.RandomUUID().toString()).
..
.clientSecret("secret").
..
build();
```

> POSTMAN: POST METHOD RESPONSE

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

**Solution:**
Encode the client's secret password using your password encoder.

```
var registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
..
//Password Must be encoded otherwise you get error 401 unauthorized error if password encoder is implemented
.clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
..
.build();
```

> POSTMAN: POST METHOD RESPONSE

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiI1OTN*******LJMsPqWQ",
    "refresh_token": "q7e9wJa3U7_LfVJ4*****go4RRl6C",
    "scope": "openid",
    "id_token": "eyJraWQi******************NDixrYaA",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 35999
}
```

Hope this is helpful! I found the hint through the resolved Github issues.

> Link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/353

Answer (score 0):

This is my application.yml of Spring Authorization Server:

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: "victoria"
      password: "password"
    oauth2:
      authorization-server:
        client:
          portfolio-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "portfolio-client"
              client-secret: "{noop}secret"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
              require-authorization-consent: true
              redirect-uris:
                - "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback"
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    org.springframework.security: TRACE

server:
  port: 8091
```

After you start authorization server, go to http://localhost:8091/.well-known/openid-configuration in browser, you will see openid configuration. You will need "authorization_endpoint" and "token_endpoint" urls for Postman.

```
{
    "issuer": "http://localhost:8091",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/authorize",
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/device_authorization",
    "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/token",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/jwks",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/connect/logout",
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code"
    ],
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
    ],
    "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/revoke",
    "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8091/oauth2/introspect",
    "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "S256"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid"
    ]
}
```

You need the rest from application.yml to put in Postman, like this:
[image]

Then you should get your token when you click "Get New Access Token" after you type "victoria" and "password" in popped up dialog.